# Dynamically load firebase config params for different environments

Tags: environment-variables, firebase-cloud-messaging, electron, dynamic-loading

I am using firebase topic subscription to push notifications in my Electron app. As of now I am hardcoding all the config properties like authorization key, topic, senderId etc in my app. Is there any way I can access these params based on the environments?

In short instead of hardcoding config properties are there ways to load it dynamically after packaging the app?